# Take db script in sql server 2008 (only updates)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate the database script of sql server 2008. I want to generate only updates from particular date. how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kind of unclear. Do you want to generate a database script that creates the tables or inserts data?

If it is data you can create selects that outputs what would be valid inserts:

```
create table test (a int, b int, c int);

select 'insert into test (a,b,c) values
    ('+convert(varchar, a)+','+convert(varchar, b)+','+convert(varchar, c)+');' 
    from test
```

On the select you could add a where clause where you only obtain data from a given date.

Edit:
It looks like someone has discussed how to find changes between databases already on some other discussion forum. Have a look at:

http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=27234

Comment: not sure why someone downvoted an obviously well intentioned answer to a vague question.  +1 for making an effort

Comment: See, I have made changes in relationships , columns and data also on date of let say 3 day before. So I want script of changes in DB design after changed (3'rd Day) day to current day. what have to do then ?

Comment: do you have two different databases, one dev and one prod?  or did you make the changes to the main databases?  if you don't have a copy of the databases in some form, you don't have anything to compare it to and script out the changes.

Comment: Yes , that is why I am asking. If Sql server have any internal mapping of the changes from 'this' date to 'this' date. Then it will sure this should happens there. I am not maintaining the 2 db. I have single one as dev. (No back up). So I am wondering that , sql serve must have to provide such facility. isn't it ? Because normal developer buying the licenses from Microsoft. He must think this facillity should availabale.